# Is there a way to handle button clicks from Backendless push notification in code and how to do it?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, backendless

I'm building android application with push notifications using Backendless as backend. I encountered a problem with handling buttons. I know that I can push notification with template(from Backendless Console) and there is an option to handle clicks, but I wonder if there is an option to do it all in code, not with template?

I have also searched for similar questions but everything I found was old and deprecated.
[image]

I use this function to push notification but I don't know how to set buttons and how to handle button clicks.

```java
public static void sendPushNotification(String channel, String message, String header,
                                            List<String> devices) {

        DeliveryOptions deliveryOptions = new DeliveryOptions();
        deliveryOptions.setPushSinglecast(devices);

        PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions();
        publishOptions.putHeader("android-ticker-text", header);
        publishOptions.putHeader("android-content-title", header);
        publishOptions.putHeader("android-content-text", message);

        Backendless.Messaging.publish(channel, message, publishOptions, deliveryOptions,
                new AsyncCallback<MessageStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(MessageStatus response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Solution :
https://support.backendless.com/t/customise-push-notification/10863/20

Answer (score 0):

I finally found answer, if you had similar problem please go here and check:
https://support.backendless.com/t/customise-push-notification/10863/20